# Arrange the excel retention data

Tags: excel, retention

I have a excel that contain retention information, and try to arrange them.

My Excel:
[image]

And try to move row to left.Is there any basic method for thison excel?

Result:
[image]

Comment: First image is my excel and I try to do like second image.I have a lot of row like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like:

[image]

The formula I used in `I2` translates to:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$F$6,ROW(),COLUMN(B2)+ROW()-2),"")
```

You can obviously apply this to your range.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.That solved my problem.I applied and it was solved.